# How to represent similar objects with different data

Tags: java, web-services, oop, soap, object-oriented-analysis

We have the following situation.  We have a couple of repositories that hold documents.  We have written front-end services that deal with documents and document data across the different repositories.  We have operations that allow you to, among other things, store new documents and retrieve document metadata.

The problem is, there are different types of documents in the repositories that each have different sets of metadata.  For example, all documents in one repository have document name, date added, size, ID, document type and document source.  Billing documents also have billing account number and customer name.  Policy documents have policy number, insured name and agency code.  Some special policy documents also have effective date and packet type.

In the second repository, documents have document name, date added, size, type and location.  Invoices (which are Billing documents in the other repository) have account number and customer name, but also invoice date.  Policy documents have policy number, insured name, agency code, effective date and policy type.  Some special policy documents have cancellation date and amount due.

The reality is more complicated, but this represents the basic issue I'm having.

I don't really have control over the existing metadata fields.  Those are defined elsewhere and some of it's legacy.  Also, these are SOAP web services, but will eventually become RESTful. But for now, they're defined by a WSDL.

So, what's the best way to represent these things that have many similarities, but some differences?

Some of the considerations:

- I'd like to shield the client from as much repository-specific info as possible.  In a perfect world, the client shouldn't care if the doc is from one repository or another, although the different fields may make this a pipe dream.
- I'd like a single newDocument and getDocumentProperties call to accept and return the pertinent data for each type, rather than have individual new and get calls for each different document type.

I could go with one big fat object with all possible fields and an enum to tell them apart, but that means the client has to magically know what fields apply and what don't.

I could go with a specific object for each possible set of document fields, but then the client has to know whether the doc is going to or coming from a particular repository which is more than I want them to know.

For now, I've gone with the best (or worst?) of both worlds, going with a few high-level abstractions (Policy document, Billing document), converting where I can and leaving any unknown or undefined data for that abstraction empty.

But this means that the client still has to know that, for example, for some Billing docs you'll have invoice date, but for others you won't.  Or that for docs from one repository you'll have an ID but for the other you'll have location.

Anyway, I'm looking for best practices for dealing with these sorts of similar, but different objects.

Answer (score 1):

> So, what's the best way to represent these things that have many similarities, but some differences?

I think the approach to how to represent/model the data depends on your application requirements and there isn't a globally accepted best practice I know of, some (all?) of the options are:

1. Map document fields with key value pairs
2. One fat object with every possible field.
3. Slim hierarchy with classes containing only shared fields.
4. Slim hierarchy + dynamic meta-data (e.g. BillingDocument only contains shared fields and also contains a map that contains fields unique to this repository)
5. Complex hierarchy with sub classes to hold the unique fields (e.g. BaseBillingDocument, RepoOneBillingDocument, Repo2BillingDocument)

> Some of the considerations:
>
> I'd like to shield the client from as much repository-specific info as possible. In a perfect world, the client shouldn't care if the doc is from one repository or another, although the different fields may make this a pipe dream.

This is a business issue not a technical one, normalise the data by either discarding unnecessary fields, declare them as optional and should be expected to be empty at times, compute missing values if they are derived from other common attributes or live with the fact that you have different sub types of the same document (BillingDocRepo1, BillingDocRepo2)

> I'd like a single newDocument and getDocumentProperties call to accept and return the pertinent data for each type, rather than have individual new and get calls for each different document type.

This is almost doable in all representations, inheritance and polymorphism are supported in both REST and SOAP web services and also doable if your using dynamic schema (a map for instance or class with metadata)